# Their + Singular or plural nouns

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural

> Most of the employees prefer to eat their ***lunch/lunches*** at their ***desk or desks***.

My question is: is it lunch/lunches and desk or desks?
Is the word "their" here referring to individual or employees as a group?

Comment: "Their" can have a distributive meaning, so "Most of the employees prefer to eat their lunch at their desk" is the preferred construction.

Answer (score 3):

This is a notoriously thorny area. But basically, **lunch** is preferred in your sentence. For **desk** / **desks**, it is less clear, but I prefer **desks**:

- Most of the employees prefer to eat their lunch at their desks.

If you try to do a strict grammatical analysis of this sentence, you will run into problems. You have to accept that *they/their* is in the middle of a prolonged grammatical shift whereby it is coming to take over more singular functions.

There are other factors involved in my choices above: For example, *lunch* is usually an uncountable noun, whereas *desk* is countable. To make the whole thing more natural:

- Most employees prefer to eat lunch at their desk[s].