# General statements: People... their + singular noun

Tags: grammar

This is a writing task in my IELTS practice test book

Nowadays, a growing number of people with health problems are trying alternative medicines and treatments instead of visiting their usual **doctor**.
Do you think this is a positive development?

I have asked many native speakers, they explained to me that because generally, each person has 1 doctor, so that the word "doctor" is used in singular form.
This means I think that "their" here means "each person".

But I have another opinion, that if "their" means "people in general", then each person has **1 doctor**, so that people has their **doctors** ( people in plural form have doctors in plural from). Can I use the word "doctors" (plural form) in this sentence with the same meaning?

Here is another example:

Nowadays, people spending more time away from their **homes** because they spend longer in their workplace. Discuss the advantages and disadvantages.

In this example, people use plural form instead. Can I use singular form **"home"** instead?

For general statement with the subject "people", I don't know when "their" means each person, or their mean people in general.

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270291/their-singular-or-plural-nouns). The second example should be _People **are** spending..._. I would use _away from home_, but with _their_ either singular or plural is possible.

Comment: Hi, I already read that thread, is that both singular form and plural form have the same meaning for my 2 examples?

Comment: @LEHANH Why do you think "doctor" or "home" would have different rules to "lunch" and "desk"?

Comment: Yes - I've just said that you can use either in the second example, and so you can in the first.

Comment: @Kate, this means if I use “doctors “ (plural form), the meaning still is that each person have 1 doctor. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH: if you use the plural, that becomes ambiguous: it allows that people might have more than one doctor each.

Comment: With “doctors “ in plural form. This could be each person have 1 doctor, but it also could mean that each person have several doctors. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the p0lural or the singular form may be used here. Either is valid grammatically, and either might be used and would be understood by a fluent speaker.

It is perhaps somewhat more common when speaking of "people in general" or any large and poorly defined group, to use a singular form, as if speaking of each individual member of the group. member. But sometimes this doesn't seem to work well, or a writer chooses the plural form as a matter of style. That is fine.

One can also start with "A person" instead of "people", speaking of s typical example, and using singular forms.

As a comment by  Kate Bunting pointed out:

> Nowadays, people spending more time away from their homes because they spend longer in their workplace.

is in error, and should  be:

> Nowadays, people **are** spending more time away from their homes because they spend longer in their **workplaces**.

The verb "are" is needed here, and if "homes" is to be plural, so should "workplaces".

Comment: How about the example of “doctor”. Both singular form and plural form can be used with the same meaning. Right?

Comment: Yes, either form may be used in the "doctor" example, and most similar constructions.,

Comment: With “doctors “ in plural form. This could mean each person have 1 doctor, but it also could mean that each person have several doctors. Right?

Comment: @LE HA Yes it could. But even the singular form, being an obvious generalization, does not rule out more than one doctor per person, in my view.

Comment: How about this sentence: People often make a lot of mistakes in (their live)/( their lives). Both form are correct. Right?

Comment: @LE HA No. The singular form "make a lot of mistakes in their live" is not correct. Please ask a separate question for a fuller explanation. There are at least two issues with this sentence, too much to address in a comment.

Comment: I already posted a different post for this sentence. It seems that each native speakers have different opinion on this matter. Please take a look at my post. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322706/general-statement-people-often-make-a-lot-of-mistakes-in-their-live-their-l/322710#322710