# Cases where "their + singular noun" is preferred

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I learned three cases where "their + singular noun" is preferred.

1, The noun is an shared object.

> The couple love their **life** together.  (their shared life)

2, [It is perhaps somewhat more common when speaking of "people in general" or any large and poorly defined group, to use a singular form, as if speaking of each individual member of the group member. But sometimes this doesn't seem to work well. Or a writer chooses the plural form as a matter of style. Or uses "a person" instead of "people", speaking of a typical example, and using singular forms.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322570/general-statements-people-their-singular-noun)

> Nowadays, a growing number of people with health problems are trying
> alternative medicines and treatments instead of visiting their usual
> **doctor**.
>
> Nowadays, people are spending more time away from their **home**
> because they spend longer in their **workplace**.

3, [Some words like lunch are usually uncountable nouns.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/270291/their-singular-or-plural-nouns)

> Most employees prefer to eat **lunch** at their **desk[s]**. (desk or
> desks depends on personal preferences)

Still, when I come across a long text, I have trouble using what I learned to analyze.

> When deciding between postgraduate studies and work, students should
> consider a variety of factors, including their career **plans**, financial
> **status** and personal preferences.
>
> The first factor that undergraduate students should consider is their
> intended **career**.
>
> The second factor that students should take into consideration is
> their financial **situation**.
>
> The final factor that undergraduate students should consider is their
> own personal preferences. Some students may have entrepreneurial
> **ambitions** and dream of running their own **business**.
>
> By taking career **goals**, financial status and personal preferences into
> consideration, students can improve their **chances** of making an optimal
> choice.

I think throughout the essay "they" speaks of a single student. "Status" is usually an uncountable noun, so I have no problem with that. But for the rest nouns, why some are plural, some singular? Is the author's every choice well-considered?

Comment: This is a proofing question and therefore not allowed...

Comment: It's talking about many students, but each has only one financial situation etc.

Comment: Did you research this topic before asking? There are several questions on this site that ask about this exact issue.

Comment: I've edited the question to add research and details about where I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This advice is being offered to the entire student population (hence the consistent use of **students** and **they**). However, the advice itself is about the behavior of individual students: A single student may have more than one **ambition**, and that student ought to maximize his/her/their **chances** of making an optimal choice. On the other hand, it is unlikely that an individual student has more than one **financial situation**, or that they dream of running more than one **business**, at least as long as they're students :)